# Using SQL with elastic search and tire

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

With my current setup I need to add some custom SQL statement that scopes some data with the Tire Gem.

I'm using Rails 3.2 with Ruby 1.9.3

In my Listing controller, I have the following:

```
@listings = Listing.search()
```

For my Listing.rb, I'm using the search methods with a number of filters such as:

```
def self.search(params={})
    tire.search(load: true, page: params[:page], per_page: 50) do |search|
      search.query  { string params[:query], :default_operator => "AND" } if params[:query].present?
      search.filter :range, posted_at: {lte: DateTime.now}
      search.filter :term, "property.rooms_available"   => params[:property_rooms_available]  if params[:property_rooms_available].present?
      search.filter :term, "property.user_state"        => params[:property_user_state]       if params[:property_user_state].present?
  
   ...
end
```

What I need to do is add this SQL statement into the search method so that it scopes by the lonitude and latitute. The 'coords' are passed in by parameters in the URL in the form

```
http://localhost:3000/listings?coords=51.0000,-01.0000 52.0000,-02.0000
```

(there is a white space between the -01.0000 and 52.0000.)

Currently I have:

```
 sql = "SELECT title, properties.id, properties.lng,properties.lat from listings WHERE ST_Within(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(' || lat || ' ' || lng || ')'),ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON((#{coords}))'));"
```

I thought about trying to scope it within the controller by something like this?

```
def self.polyed(coords)
    joins(:property).
    where("ST_Within(ST_GeometryFromText('POINT(' || properties.lat || ' ' || properties.lng || ')'),ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON((#{coords}))'))").
    select("title, properties.id, properties.lng,properties.lat")
end
```

And this...

## listings_controller.rb

```
def index
  @listings = Listing.polyed(poly_coordinates).search()
end
```

It needs to return the results as @listings by HTML and the json format

```
http://localhost:3000/listings.json?
```

I'm already using RABL to automatically produce the json.

Is this possible?

Many thanks in advance.

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to pass the options `joins`, `where`, etc. in the `:load` option.

But if you want to filter the returned results in the Rails code, a much better approach seem to be loading just record IDs with Tire (use the `fields` option to limit the fields returned), and then use them in your SQL query.